# Shell sort function not sorting the array completely

Tags: c, arrays, algorithm, sorting, debugging

I have a an array of 10 integers that I would like to sort, but the final array doesn't seem to be completely sorted.

```
// Shell sort Function

void shell_sort(int A[]){
    display_array(A);

    int k = ARRAY_SIZE / 2;
    int x = 0; // index of value that swaps with value k spaces back
    int temp = 0;

    while (k > 0){

        for (int i = ARRAY_SIZE-1; i >= k; i-- ){
            x = i;
            while( (x - k) >= 0 ){

                if ( A[x] < A[x-k] ){
                    temp = A[x];
                    A[x] = A[x-k];
                    A[x-k] = temp;
                    x -= k ;
                }
                else{
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        printf("k=%d\n",k);
        display_array(A);
        k /= 2;
    }
}
```

This is the input and output:

```
Input:  int A[ARRAY_SIZE] = {15,4,6,2,7,8,44,1,9,3};


Output: 
Input
15  4   6   2   7   8   44  1   9   3   
k = 5
8   4   1   2   3   15  44  6   9   7   
k = 2
1   2   8   4   3   6   9   15  44  7   
k = 1
1   2   3   8   4   6   7   9   15  44
```

Could you point out where I'm going wrong?

Comment: The `k=5` step worked because there are only two items in each list. The `k=2` step needs to sort `{8,1,3,44,9}` and `{4,2,15,6,7}`. But the orders after the `k=2` step are `{1,8,3,9,44}` and `{2,4,6,15,7}`. So the code doesn't handle arrays of length 3 or more properly. My suggestion is to set `k=1` using an input array of `{8,1,3,44,9}` and consider why the code doesn't sort that array properly.

Comment: What is the reasoning behind k /= 2?  Shouldn't you go through all the gaps

Comment: hmm.. I change k to 1 and used {8,1,3,44,9} as the array. I got this as the answer    [1 8 3 9 44].  I'm trying to figure out the mistake.

Comment: @AmitKumar I just saw a video of shell sort online where they'd used k=k/2 and I tried to implement it. Would I be better off reducing the gap one by one?

Comment: @AmitKumar Any sequence can be used as long as the last `k` is 1. [Here's a list of example sequences](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shellsort#Gap_sequences).

Comment: You should pass the size of the array to the sort function, rather than using just a fixed size.  Have you looked on Wikipedia for [Shell sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shellsort)?  There are multiple gap-scanning algorithms described there.  And no, you should not be decreasing the gap by 1; shell sort works by dealing with the large amounts of disorder with the big gap and then decreasing (fairly rapidly) the gap size.  You can find a shell sort in K&R.  You can find a shell sort in Bentley's "Programming Pearls".  There are lots of places to look for them.

Comment: @user3386109 Agree, it should work with any gap value as long as last gap is 1.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I wasn't aware of the different gap sizes you could use. Thanks! I will check it out.

Comment: @wolfcubman As far as i have read, at each interval, each of the sublists should be sorted before going to the next interval, this is not handled in your case. Sublists are not fully sorted before going to the next interval. Most commonly insertion sort is used to sort the sublists. This might help http://quiz.geeksforgeeks.org/shellsort/

Comment: Note that the condition `while( (x - k) >= 0 )` is a funny, Fortran II style way of writing `while (x >= k)`, isn't it?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler haha I don't know. I've never done Fortran.

Comment: Fortran II is really old (1958), older than Fortran IV (aka Fortran 66).  And it used numeric labels, and if only had an `IF (expr) 10, 20, 30` form for the `IF` statement, which would jump to label 10 if `expr` was negative, to 20 if `expr` was zero, or to 30 if it was positive.  You could use the same label number for any 2 of the labels (there was no point in using the same label for all 3, of course). Better options were added to Fortran IV, and to each revision since then (Fortran 77, 90, 95, 2003, 2008, 2015, …). See also Wikipedia on [Fortran](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fortran).

Answer (score 0):

I changed the **k /= 2** to **k--** and I got the answer, but it took more loops. I'm not sure this is how I should do it.

Here is the output:

```
15  4   6   2   7   8   44  1   9   3   
k = 5
8   4   1   2   3   15  44  6   9   7   
k = 4
3   4   1   2   8   7   44  6   9   15  
k = 3
2   4   1   3   6   7   15  8   9   44  
k = 2
1   3   2   4   6   7   9   8   15  44  
k = 1
1   2   3   4   6   7   8   9   15  44
```

Answer (score 0):

I have refactored your program like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define ARRAY_SIZE 10
// Shell sort Function

void display_array(int A[]) {
    int i;
    for (i =0; i < ARRAY_SIZE; ++i)
        printf("%d ", A[i]);
    printf ("\n");
}

void shell_sort(int A[]){
    display_array(A);

    int temp = 0;
    int i,j,k;
    for (i = ARRAY_SIZE/2; i > 0; i = i/2 ){
        for (j = i; j < ARRAY_SIZE; ++j) {
            for (k = j -i; k >= 0; k = k - i) {
                if(A[k+i]>=A[k])
                    break;
                else
                    {
                        temp=A[k];
                        A[k]=A[k+i];
                        A[k+i]=temp;
                    }
                printf("k=%d\n",k);
                display_array(A);
            }
        }
    }
}

int main(void) {
    // your code goes here
    int A[ARRAY_SIZE] = {15,4,6,2,7,8,44,1,9,3};
    shell_sort(A);
    return 0;
}
```

I see the following output:

```
15 4 6 2 7 8 44 1 9 3
k=0
8 4 6 2 7 15 44 1 9 3
k=2
8 4 1 2 7 15 44 6 9 3
k=4
8 4 1 2 3 15 44 6 9 7
k=0
1 4 8 2 3 15 44 6 9 7
k=1
1 2 8 4 3 15 44 6 9 7
k=2
1 2 3 4 8 15 44 6 9 7
k=5
1 2 3 4 8 6 44 15 9 7
k=6
1 2 3 4 8 6 9 15 44 7
k=7
1 2 3 4 8 6 9 7 44 15
k=4
1 2 3 4 6 8 9 7 44 15
k=6
1 2 3 4 6 8 7 9 44 15
k=5
1 2 3 4 6 7 8 9 44 15
k=8
1 2 3 4 6 7 8 9 15 44
```

Please note the comments mentioned in the question. You should pass array size to functions. This however is a crude implementation.

**EDIT**

Further refactored code looks like this below:

```
void shell_sort(int A[]){
    display_array(A);

    int k = ARRAY_SIZE/2; // This is the offset you want to begin with 
    int j = 0; // index of value that swaps with value k spaces back
    int temp = 0;
    int i;

    while (k > 0){
        // browse through the later half of the array k to ARRAY SIZE
        for (i = k; i < ARRAY_SIZE; i++ ) {
            j = i;
            int temp = A[i];
            // As long as j >= k, check if values can be swapped  
            while( (j - k) >= 0 && A[j-k] > temp ){
                A[j] = A[j-k];
                j = j -k;
            }
            // finally insert the correct value at j
            A[j] = temp;
        }
        printf("k=%d\n",k);
        display_array(A);
        k = k/2;
    }
}
```

With this change, we see the following output which is desired:

```
15 4 6 2 7 8 44 1 9 3
k=5
8 4 1 2 3 15 44 6 9 7
k=2
1 2 3 4 8 6 9 7 44 15
k=1
1 2 3 4 6 7 8 9 15 44
```

[check-refectored-code](http://ideone.com/9oICmQ)

Hope this helps.

Comment: I'd like to know what's wrong with my program than this implementation. Also, the value of k (the gaps) should be as low as possible for the program to be efficient. What you've done is a straight- up insertion sort rather than a shell sort. Thanks.

Comment: I have implemented shell sorting and not insertion sorting. Shell sorting itself is a generalized version of insertion sort.